# docker linux host not applying port forwarding

Tags: docker, portforwarding

I am doing development on windows docker, using Linux images. Hosting in windows, the port forwarding setting are applied correctly. However when pulling into Linux docker host, the port settings are not getting applied for some reason. Anyone have any insight? this is very weird...

So in windows, docker inspect will show me:

```
"Ports" : {
 "80/tcp":[
{
 "HostIp" : "0.0.0.0",
 "HostPort" : "8675"
}
 ]
}
```

the above scenario is good, and works as expected

However when pushing it to repository and pulling into Linux the following occurs:

```
"Ports" : {
 "80/tcp" : null
}
```

Comment: Can you share the logs after running `docker logs <container name>`?

Comment: recent logs don't show any errors....i can get it to run when i manually do a docker run -p....but when i pull it from the repo, for some reason the port bindings are not applied

Comment: this is a .net core api btw

Comment: Port binding only applies when you run, not when you pull.

Comment: right, so when i start/install the container, shouldn't the defined bindings get applied? does the pull not do this?

Comment: Chances are the port 8675 is being used. Can you check `docker run` without another port?

Comment: i will say, i do have a docker-compose file as well....do i need to do a different kind of push?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using docker-compose as it was meant. Made life a lot easier!